# Parse JSON using GSON in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I have JSON data like this and I want to parse using GSON in Kotlin

```
{"items":["Green Tea","19,90"]}
```

First item is name of product, second is price of product.

I am not really sure how to do it. Json format is correct. Do I have to create data class? How it should look like?

Comment: json count is static or dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make two data classes like

```kotlin
data class MainItem(val items: List<ItemsDataClass>)

data class ItemsDataClass(val name: String, val price: String)
```

And after that parse MainItem from your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

After Giorgi answer and some research I have result:

```
class Items(val items: List<String>)
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val getItem = gson.fromJson(body, Items::class.java)
val result = getItem.items

runOnUiThread {
    textView.append(result[0].toString() + " " + result[1].toString())
              }
```

Comment: With this solution you don't have to call `.toString()` as you already defined `items` as a List of Strings. You could also use String Template for shortening: `textView.append("${result[0]} ${result[1]}");`

Comment: @BenjaminBur Thank you - I didn´t know that